# php alternatives to ip2long/long2ip

Tags: php, math, ip

I've been trying to come up with a way to store IP addresses as unsigned integers with PHP but I guess I'm not familiar enough with how it done to come up with proper functions. Here's what I came up with (wrong as it is):

```
// ip 2 unsigned int
function ip2int($ipaddress) {
    // turns IP into signed integer
    $signed = ip2long($ipaddress);
    $unsigned = sprintf("%u", $signed);
    return $unsigned;
    }

// unsigned int 2 ip
function int2ip($unsigned) {
    $signed = sprintf("%d", $unsigned);
    $ipaddress = long2ip($signed);
    return $ipaddress;
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: So you basically want to convert a signed int to an unsigned int? Then use `pack`. Why though?

Answer (score 0):

long2ip converts an integer into the IP format and ip2long does vice versa
Use like this

```
$long = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);//or your ip
$ip   = long2ip($long);
```

Comment: right but it converts them as a signed int, anyway to preserve them as unsigned ints?